Using hyperlink to make telegram bot with python
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 1325, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_handlers\basehandler.py", line 157, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\aqilj\Documents\JavedPython\Bot_Tele\Telegram_bot.py", line 11, in start_command
    await update.message.reply_text (
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_message.py", line 1705, in reply_text
    return await self.get_bot().send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_extbot.py", line 2893, in send_message
    return await super().send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 1024, in send_message
    return await self._send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_extbot.py", line 608, in _send_message
    result = await super()._send_message(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 740, in _send_message
    result = await self._post(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 618, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_extbot.py", line 353, in _do_post
    return await super()._do_post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 647, in _do_post
    result = await request.post(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_baserequest.py", line 200, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aqilj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_baserequest.py", line 381, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 151

I use "parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2" for hyperlink and library
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from typing import Final
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes


You've to correctly format the text when you're using MarkdownV2 parsing mode. Seems like you're missing a closing entity. Update your question to include the actual code where the exception occurs, that would help in troubleshooting.
